# Trying to extract the "Motherboard Name" as a String variable value

Tags: c#, string, system.management

I'm new here, but I used the forum so many times just to save my mind from heating-up. Today I'm trying to code a software/script to get the motherboard name, using it as a string value and converting the string to a HEX code. **But, let's focus on the "Using it as a string value"**.

I used a code just for some tests to get the [Mobo](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mobo#:%7E:text=mobo%20in%20British%20English,a%20motherboard) name. It acts pretty good, but now I'm stuck in the part to convert it as a string value. Can you guys give me some help?

Here is the code that I'm using, ignore the last field, that's just me testing the HEX converter.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

    public class Programa
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

        //MOBO NAME AND SERIAL GRABBER (REMEMBER TO REMOVE THE SERIAL)

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Product, SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard"))
            {
            ManagementObjectCollection information = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in information)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData data in obj.Properties)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", data.Name, data.Value);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            //HEX CONVERTER

            string value = "AiPapi";

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

            string hexString = Convert.ToHexString(bytes);

            Console.WriteLine($"String value: \"{value}\"");
            Console.WriteLine($"   Hex value: \"{hexString}\"");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `data.Value.ToString()` the string value...?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could get away here with just

```cs
private string FindFirstMoboName()
{
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Product FROM Win32_BaseBoard"))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
        {
            var prod = obj["Product"];
            if(prod != null) return prod.ToString();
        }
    }
    return "<no motherboard>";  // would be better to throw
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I got no output, seems like the private string is unused, and the return is classified as a possible null reference return. I will post a screenshot of what I did with your code, correct me if I'm wrong (Probably)

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/JYLiseXQ8fOH

Comment: Added a null check for you.

Comment: Tried again, but the same null reference appears. Using the code that I included in my post and doing some changes, I managed to extract only the name without the "Product" and as a string, but now, how can I use that string outside that "context", as when I try, it says that the name doesn't exist in the current context. Here's the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/WiK9sFNYfee8

Comment: That's exactly why I wrote this as a separate function you can simply call: `string mnstring = FindFirstMoboName();`

Comment: So, as I'm pretty newbie in the programming world, I couldn't make your suggestion work in the code, always saying that the "FindFIrstMoboName" is never used and the "prod.ToString" is null. I started searching here in stack overflow again, and I saw a guy asking about these "contexts", and then I saw a way to grab the result of a "context" that is like this: https://prnt.sc/piBPF6nj53J4

Tell me what you think about it.

Comment: One more thing, I added the "ArgumentNullException" just to remove that boring warning. https://prnt.sc/Iwvuwhmbx2LE